# Aliases cached for bash/zsh

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, zsh, alias

I'm working on a cli tool that manages aliases. When I create an `alias_file` and then add to my bashrc or zshrc via something like `source $HOME/alias_file` the aliases work as expected. However, when I remove them, they still seem to work until I add a new alias that does something different. Then that change is picked up.

Not really a big deal as it changes the action when I add something new, however, I'm wondering if anybody knows what is going on with this... is there some sort of caching going on?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760505/is-it-possible-to-unsource-in-bash) thread should answer your questions.

Comment: Are you starting new shells, or just expecting them to vanish from existing shells? If the latter, that's not how they work at all.

Comment: In bash, there's [`unalias`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-unalias); not sure about Zsh.

Comment: @BenjaminW. that seems to be about the only thing that works! Do you have any more insight as to why even after the alias is removed from the file and the session reloaded, its still available until `unalias` is ran? Are all aliases stored in some cache somewhere?

Comment: tried to `source $HOME/.bashrc` after removing `alias_file`?

Comment: When you say "session reloaded", how are you reloading? A new shell shouldn't inherit any aliases.

Comment: @AlexMawashi Sourcing again without the aliases isn't going to remove the aliases.

Comment: The alias file is not a configuration file; it's basically a shell script that executes a series of `alias` commands. If you want to unset an alias, you have to do so explicitly with an appropriate `unalias` command.

Comment: Yeah, I think that makes sense with understanding alias as a script that is run, not  just text loaded in from a file each time a session is started!

Comment: Just sourcing something, won't automatically remove definitions which are already present. This is fortunate, otherwise we never can include definitions from more than one file. Think about ordering beer from two shops: When the second shop delivers its beer, the one which the old shop has brought already does not suddenly disappear. This idea applies to aliases, functions and variable settings as well.